# Trying to count categories variables in R using rowSums

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a count for each of the observation categories per row.

In the example of the data below, the top line containing photo, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 is the headers and the line beneath that contains the observations.

I would do it in excel with countif however dataset is huge with this only being a tiny sample. Plus screw excel :)

```
photo          2           3              4        5          6        
30001004501  SINV_SPO_V  SINV_HYD    LSUB_SAND   Unc     SINV_SPO_V
```

I'm trying to do it so that it will create a new column for each observation I count, ie if I were trying to determine the frequency of "Unc" would have its own column with how many times "Unc" was counted for each row.

The code below is one of the things I've tried over the last couple of days as well as variations of count and length commands but with no success

```
data$Unc <-rowSums(data[,3:52] == "Unc", na.rm = F)
```

I'm trying to get R to only count the columns between 3 and 52

Thanking in advance for any help is getting incredibly frustrating as I know it should be really easy

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Please use `dput` to show your data.

Comment: Maybe `table(as.character(data[3:52]))` to count the frequency of each individual item across all rows. If you need something more complicated, please do the following: copy the result of `df <- data[1:10]; dput(df)`. copy the result of `dput`. Then show us your expected output for this simpler example.

Answer (score 1):

So if i understood your request correctly this is a data.table solution of your problem, you can use 3:52 in measure.vars for your task. Also this only works if photo is a unique id variable, if it isn't you should create one yourself and use that instead

```
library(data.table)
# create example data.table
dt <- data.table(photo = 1:6,
                 x1 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "d"),
                 x2 = c("c", "c", "a", "c", "a", "d"),
                 x3 = c("c", "c", "a", "c", "a", "d"))

# Melt data.table, select which columns you need
dt_melt <- melt.data.table(dt, id.vars = 'photo', measure.vars = 2:3, variable.name = 'column')
# Get a resulting data.table with pairs of photo and observation
result_dt <- dt_melt[, .N, by = c('photo', 'value')]

   photo value N
1:     1     a 1
2:     2     b 1
3:     3     a 2
4:     4     c 2
5:     5     a 2
6:     6     d 2
7:     1     c 1
8:     2     c 1

# For wide representation
dcast(result_dt, photo ~ value, value.var = 'N', fill = 0)

   photo a b c d
1:     1 1 0 1 0
2:     2 0 1 1 0
3:     3 2 0 0 0
4:     4 0 0 2 0
5:     5 2 0 0 0
6:     6 0 0 0 2
```

Comment: Maybe add `dcast(result_dt, photo ~ value, value.var = 'N', fill = 0)` to get the wide representation OP wants?

Comment: @Jaap Missed that part, added!

Answer (score 0):

I think that a way to solve your problem is to use the `table` function:

```
col1 <- c('a','b','b','b','a','c','b','a','c')
col2 <- c('d','e','d','d','d','d','d','d','e')
data = data.frame(col1,col2)
table(col1)
table(col2)
tab = table(data)
tab
margin.table(tab,1)
margin.table(tab,2)
```

`table(col1)` will give you the frequencies for the categorical variables of `col1`, and this gives the same result as `margin.table(tab,1)`. So it depends if you prefer to work on the data.frame or on the columns directly.